# How convert this DataFrame in vectors?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working with Scala and have the following REPL output:

```
scala> val result = sql("Select col.pid, explode(col.tracks.track_uri) as track_uri From table")

scala> result.show(5)
+---+--------------------+
|pid|           track_uri|
+---+--------------------+
|  0|    0Uaiui7t32423WM5|
|  0|    6I97G45hbhJGkjhg|
|  0|    0Wqfhbf6fhbHJG34|
|  0|    1AW77b76KJVG7h6r|
|  0|    1lzkjd7HG8hjkjh9|
......
|45986|    k7sjHG8789jvgk|
+---+--------------------+
```

I want to convert it to this way:

```
pid     track1             track2              .....      trackN
0       0Uaiui7t32423WM5   6I97G45hbhJGkjhg    . . . 1lzkjd7HG8hjkjh9 
1          .
2          .
n       k7sjHG8789jvgk      .... .....                   ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't `explode`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

(0 until N).foldLeft(spark.table("table"))((df, i) => 
  df.withColumn(s"track$i", col("col.tracks.track_uri").getItem(i))
)
```

Comment: perfect. Thanks you